# ASP.NET return different enum types from the view to the same controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have a controller with multiple views. Each view returns a parameter called actionType that in which every view returns a different enum type (for example, ElectricEnum, PaperlessEnum, DigitalEnum). In my controller action, I have it set to receive a type Enum named actionType. The default is set to null. However, I'm having trouble getting the param to fill with data, it always returns null no matter what.

Here is an example of code from a view and the method header...

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadCSVReport", "Public", FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("fromDate", Model.StatsByDate.Parameters.FromDate)
            @Html.Hidden("toDate", Model.StatsByDate.Parameters.ToDate)
            @Html.Hidden("serviceType", ServiceTypeEnum.Paperless)
            @Html.Hidden("actionType", Model.StatsByDate.Parameters.ActionType)

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="download" value="Download" formmethod="post" />
        }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DownloadCSVReport(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, ServiceTypeEnum serviceType, Enum actionType = null)
    {
        string returnValue = _dashboardClient.Call(svc => svc.GetCommaSeparatedList(fromDate, toDate, serviceType, actionType));

        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.csv", "ReportDownload"));
        Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("DownloadToken", System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));    // For loader icon

        return Content(returnValue, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }
```

In this view, the value of ActionType is ElectronicEnum, but in the other views that call this DownloadCSVReport action, they are a different kind of enum...

Is it possible to solve this in this way, can I pass theses different types of enums to one destination and utilize its value?

Answer (score 0):

Model binding just looks for model properties. So what ever which isn't part of your model will be lost. Add `ActionType` to your model and you will have it in controller as property of your model.